# How to switch user (su) to the odoo account? (This account is currently not available error.)

Tags: server, sudo, users, su, odoo

How do I `su` to the `odoo` account?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo su odoo -
This account is currently not available.
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ awk -F: '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd | grep odoo
odoo
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ll /etc/odoo/odoo.conf 
-rw-r----- 1 odoo odoo 214 Dec 15 01:28 /etc/odoo/odoo.conf
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Presumably I should be [editing](https://askubuntu.com/q/1335264/847449) the `odoo.conf` file as the `odoo` user.

I can switch to root with `sudo su root -` of course.

Perhaps the answer is that "you don't" as:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ cat /etc/passwd | grep odoo
odoo:x:132:140::/var/lib/odoo:/usr/sbin/nologin
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

is this just how `odoo` is [configured](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/10331)?

Comment: You cannot switch to any user that ends in `/usr/sbin/nologin`

Comment: thanks @Terrance I didn't see that in the `passwd` file at first.  (it's glaringly obvious of course:  `nologin` couldn't be clearer.)

Comment: use `sudo -i` instead of `sudo su` to switch to root, `sudo -u user -i` for user I believe

Comment: ... and think it should be `sudo su - odoo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Presumably I should be editing the odoo.conf file as the odoo user."

No.

Make the file writable for group and add your admin user to the `odoo` group.
Use ...

```
sudo chown 660 /etc/odoo/odoo.conf
sudo usermod -a -G odoo $USER
```

... and there is no  need for switching and you can use  your normal admin account. It is the easiest and best method to allow permission to edit the file.

Comment: thanks, I'll have to try this.